# Magento 2 CMS Page URL redirect 2.3.5

Tags: cms, cms-pages, routing, routes

I want to redirect a custom URL and change the URL path ONLY.
If my URL is [www.domain.com/about-company](http://www.domain.com/about-company) or [www.domain.com/product-a-faq](http://www.domain.com/product-a-faq)

I want these to be shown in different URL
examples -> [www.domain.com/about-company](http://www.domain.com/about-company) I want this to be shown as [www.domain.com/my-compnay/about](http://www.domain.com/my-compnay/about).

second URL -> [www.domain.com/product-a-faq](http://www.domain.com/product-a-faq) I want this to be shown as [www.domain.com/product-a/product-faq](http://www.domain.com/product-a/product-faq)

is this possible if it is please can someone help me to write a module or guide me?

I want to do this programmatically because I have added an attribute if that is enabled the URL should redirect.

Comment: Add url rewrite for it in the backend Marketing -> URL Rewrites

Comment: i want to do it programmatically i have over 150 cms pages

Comment: Check this blog of how to add url rewrites programatically https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-url-rewrite-programmatically.html

Comment: If your CMS pages have something in common in the URL you can do it programmatically or maybe creating a multiselect in system.xml containing all the CMS pages, and then for every CMS page go and check if that page should be redirected based on the configuration, otherwise if it's just a one time thing, maybe it's better doing them from Marketing -> Url rewrites.

Comment: @RahulBarot I couldn't get that working i looked at that eariler

Comment: @AlanZavagli how can i do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observer

Declare the event

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="redirectcustomer" instance="Vendor\CheckUrl\Observer\RedirectCustom" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then in the Oberserver catch the Url with this :

```
/**
 * @var Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $_urlInterface;


$currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
```

Then you just have to check if this url match the one you want `domin.com/about-company` and if it does you make the redirection you want.

```
$redirectUrl = XXX;
$resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse('200');
```

Comment: will this contain the content from about-company. or would this be an empty page

Comment: The whole point is that you can bring it to any page you would like. But to be honest, if your objective is just to change the url pattern; then you rather just do it outside of magento with htaccess; or inside magento as already said above with Url rewrites...but it won't be programmatically.  With this solution, you will go to the page pointed by `redirectUrl`. I think there is also some methods just to change the url without redirecting. May be it suits you better to do that.

Comment: Hi @claims i want to do it programmatically i am doing a check if the cms page has a special attribute enabled. i have looked into redirect Url for cms page but i wasn't able to find a example